# UIimageView and Acessory View to work separately in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on on an app similar to Apple reminders app. I have a tableView with data. The cell has an UIImageView and Disclosure Indicator accessory view. When any of its row is selected, a view controller is pushed.

I would like for the UIImageView of each row to work separately from the row selection as it is in Apple reminders app. How can I do that?

I have tried UIimageview as subview for the cell and added UITapGestureRecognizer to it. It worked fine with last inserted row but did not with other rows.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than subclass UIImageView, you might consider subclassing UITableViewCell. In your subclass, you can still add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView, but you would target a method on your cell's subclass (rather than your table controller, although you didn't say what the handler is currently targeting).

Add a tapRecognizer to your custom cell's UIImageView, and have a BOOL flag on your custom cell as well  (eg, imageViewTapped). In your tap handler, set imageViewTapped to YES.

Now, your tableView controller is still going to get calls to for didSelectRowWithIndexPath, regardless of whether or not the tap was on the imageVIew. So, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, evaluate the custom cell's imageViewTapped property. If the flag has been set, push viewController A (for the imageView behavior) on your navigation stack. If imageViewTapped == NO, push viewController B (presumably what you're already transitioning to).

Answer (score 1):

@Adel. You can put a transparent button on the imageView to respond to user's touch.

```
CGRect imageRect = (CGRect){100, 100, 100, 100};
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect] autorelease];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIButton *maskBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
maskBtn.frame = imageView.bounds;
maskBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[maskBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(maskBtnDidClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[imageView addSubview:maskBtn];
```

Notice that imageView's userInteractionEnabled is NO by default.
Hope helps.
:)