# How to push a new view tapping programmatically added UiImageViews in a custom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, view, push

I want to make it so when I tap on an image in a UITableViewCell, it pushes a new view and displays an UIImageView that you can manipulate (such as pinching it and expanding it).

Currently, I'm using a custom cell which adds the image to the cell programmatically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.news.imgURL count]; i++) {

        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.news.imgURL objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [image setFrame:CGRectMake(20, (labelSize.height + 25 + 14) + (i * 280), 280, 280)];
        image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        image.tag = 101 + i;
        image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.contentView addSubview:image];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1]
        [image addGestureRecognizer: tap];
    }
```

This is located in my customcell.m file.

As seen in the code above, I use a GestureRecognizer that I can detect taps of the image using the following code:

```
-(void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Image tapped!", nil);
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to push a new view from inside the customcell.m file. Is there a way to push a new view from inside the customcell.m file or must I explicitly do it from my masterviewcontroller?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719704/uiimageview-and-acessory-view-to-work-separately-in-tableviewcell/14719834#14719834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for using a delegate. Define a delegate protocol for your custom cell class. Then have your table view controller set itself up as the cell's delegate. Your protocol should have a method that tells the delegate that an image was tapped. The cell and the image could be parameters of the delegate method.

In your cell's `handleTap:` method you can check if the delegate responds to the protocol method and if it does, it calls the protocol on the delegate, passing itself (the cell) and the tapped image.

Comment: Since I enabled user interaction with my image subview, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never called in my controller (the tap event on the image supersedes the cell's. So even though my table view controller is the cell's delegate, I can't do anything when the image is tapped in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

write following code in cell tapped method **or** in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
yourViewCon *vc = [[yourViewCon alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: I added the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but it does nothing that I notice.

Answer (score 0):

First you setup a delegate in your `MyCustomCell.h`

```
@protocol MyCustomCellDelegate;
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyCustomCellDelegate> delegate;
- (void)someCustomMethod:(NSString*)stringForChangingSomethingInMyCell;
@end

@protocol MyCustomDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)itemTappedForRow:(NSUIInteger)rowNumber;
@end
```

In `MyCustomCell.m`, you synthesize the delegate:

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

And in your `handleTapMethod`:

```
// You can use self.tag to track rowNumbers
[_delegate itemTappedForRow:rowNumber];
```

Meanwhile in your table view controller`, you conform to the protocol you just defined

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController<MyCustomCellDelegate>
```

And you create the cells this way in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"yoBaby"];
cell.delegate = self;
cell.tag = indexPath.row;

return cell;
```

Finally, in `itemTappedForRow`, you push a new view controller that does the stuff for you. I'm assuming you are using a navigation controller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourNewViewControllerWithTheImageSelected animated:YES];
```

Comment: Assuming everyone is using new versions of Xcode (4.4 or later) and/or the newer compilers, there is no need for the `@synthesize` line. And references to `_delegate` should really be `self.delegate` unless there is a good reason to reference the ivar directly. Also, the protocol method should be optional, not required. If the class defining the protocol can work properly without the delegate implementing the method, then the method should be optional.

Comment: What should itemTappedForRow do? How does it connect to didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Sorry, it was a small goof up. I changed the answer. You don't have to write anything in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` anymore.